# Kafka Consumer: Stop processing messages when exception was raised

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm a bit confused about the poll() behaviour of (Spring) Kafka after/when stopping the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`.

What I want to achieve: 
Stop the consumer after an exception was raised (for example message could not be saved to the database), do not commit offset, restart it after a given time and start processing again from the previously failed message.

I read this article which says that the container will call the listener with the remaining records from the poll (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/451) which means that there is no guarantee that after the failed message a further message which was processed successfully will commit the offset. This could end up in lost/skipped messages.

Is this really the case and if yes is there a solution to solve this without upgrading the newer versions? (DLQ is not a solution for my case)

What I already did:
Setting the `setErrorHandler()` and `setAckOnError(false)`

```
private Map<String, Object> getConsumerProps(CustomKafkaProps kafkaProps,  Class keyDeserializer) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    //Set common props
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProps.getBootstrapServers());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProps.getConsumerGroupId());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); // Start with the first message when a new consumer group (app) arrives at the topic
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false); // We will use "RECORD" AckMode in the Spring Listener Container

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializer);

    if (kafkaProps.isSslEnabled()) {
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
        props.put("ssl.keystore.location", kafkaProps.getKafkaKeystoreLocation());
        props.put("ssl.keystore.password", kafkaProps.getKafkaKeystorePassword());
        props.put("ssl.key.password", kafkaProps.getKafkaKeyPassword());
    }

    return props;
}
```

Consumer

```
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> kafkaReceiverContainer(CustomKafkaProps kafkaProps) throws Exception {
    StoppingErrorHandler stoppingErrorHandler = new StoppingErrorHandler();

    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(...);
    containerProperties.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.RECORD);
    containerProperties.setAckOnError(false);
    containerProperties.setErrorHandler(stoppingErrorHandler);

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> container = ...
    container.setConcurrency(1); //use only one container
    stoppingErrorHandler.setConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(container);

    return container;
}
```

Error Handler

```
public class StoppingErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Setter
    private ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer concurrentMessageListenerContainer;

    @Value("${backends.kafka.consumer.halt.timeout}")
    int consumerHaltTimeout;

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        if (concurrentMessageListenerContainer != null) {
            concurrentMessageListenerContainer.stop();
        }

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (concurrentMessageListenerContainer != null && !concurrentMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()) {
                    concurrentMessageListenerContainer.start();
                }
            }
        }, consumerHaltTimeout);
    }
}
```

What I'm using:

```
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>

  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without upgrading the newer versions?

2.1 introduced the [ContainerStoppingErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_container_stopping_error_handlers_2) which is a `ContainerAwareErrorHandler`, the remaining unconsumed messages are discarded (and will be re-fetched when the container is restarted).

With earlier versions, your listener will need to reject (fail) the remaining messages in the batch (or set `max.records.per.poll=1`).

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot upgrade currently (planned, but until then we need a workaround) to the newest version due to some dependencies which means we cannot use the ContainerStoppingErrorHandler. Do you have some experience with setting the `max.records.per.poll` to 1 regarding the performance? And btw, do you have any thoughts on "reject (fail) the remaining messages"?

Comment: It will definitely be slower but it still might be "fast-enough" for your needs; if not, you would have to add a check in your listener to query the error handler to see if we're in a failed state, and reject all the remaining records in the batch.

Comment: Does this mean that setting ack mode to RECORD has the same meaning as setting it to BATCH when using higher value for max.records.per.poll in spring-kafka 1.3.* ? If for example I fetch 5 events in single poll, the first is OK, second fails (so i call stop), and 3,4,5 are OK - the offset will be moved to the latest in both ack modes, right?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. The offset will be 2 (or 3 if `ackOnError` is true) in both RECORD and BATCH modes.